# asks permission after dont allow tapped

Tags: ios

I am to develope this in my app.Can we do it so that the app asks permission to access contacts every time the user clicks on the invite friends button, until he/she finally accepts. Then, it doesn’t have to ask every time.

Comment: No, the permission dialog is only showed once, by the iOS SDK. You can however check the state if the state is declined you can tell the user to open the settings app to change the permission. But you will not be able to open the settings app from you app like with the permissions dialog from the iOS SDK.

Comment: Nagging a user is bad interface design.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not allowed. There are two good solutions around this though. One is to make your own pop up asking the user if they want to allow permission, and if they say yes, then proceed to ask them for apple's implementation of the permissions. Otherwise, don't show it and handle the denial appropriately. Another solution is that if you ask them for permissions and they deny it, then you can show a pop up explaining to them how to go into their settings to and allow permissions.